# Dotnet run and System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Today I have really strange problem with my application. After I moved it to another folder and called the command dotnet run application gave me an error:

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_Name' in type 'Micros
oft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationChangeTokenSource`1' from assembly 'Microsof
t.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsConfigurationServiceCollec
tionExtensions.Configure[TOptions](IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration c
onfig)
   at LicenseManager.Api.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
in D:\Projekty\LicenseManager\src\LicenseManager.Api\Startup.cs:line 61
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(ISer
viceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at LicenseManager.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projekty\LicenseManag
er\src\LicenseManager.Api\Program.cs:line 15
```

Before I moved it was working.

Here is my Startup class:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc()
                    .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented);
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("DefaultPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
            services.AddScoped<IComputerRepository, InMemoryComputerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ILicenseRepository, InMemoryLicenseRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ILicenseTypeRepository, InMemoryLicenseTypeRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRoomRepository, InMemoryRoomRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, InMemoryUserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRoomService, RoomService>();
            services.AddScoped<ILicenseTypeService, LicenseTypeService>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
            services.AddScoped<ILicenseService, LicenseService>();
            services.AddScoped<IComputerService, ComputerService>();
            services.AddScoped<IDataInitializer,DataInitializer>();
            services.AddSingleton(AutoMapperConfig.Initialize());
            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("app"));


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            //loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            //loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            //app.UseCors("DefaultPolicy");
            app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5050").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
            loggerFactory.AddNLog();
            app.AddNLogWeb();
            env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
            SeedData(app);

            app.UseMvc();

        }

        private void SeedData(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            var settings = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<AppSettings>>();
            if(settings.Value.SeedData)
            {
                var dataInitializer = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IDataInitializer>();
                dataInitializer.SeedAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to comment line 61 which is

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("app"));
```

But an application gave me another TypeLoadException.
It's the same thing when i push it to github.

Answer (score 2):

I added two references to my csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.0.0" />
```

And now dotnet run start working, but when I send for example Http.Get request the kestrel send me this message:

```
2017-09-28 10:52:28.8575|WARN|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|Connection processing ended abnormally.
```

EDIT

Finnaly application get work It was a problem with new NLog.Extensions.Logging package version 1.0.0-rtm-beta6. I went back to version 1.0.0-rtm-beta5. And application starts work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like loading your settings problem.
How do you run the app? Where is the entry point?
Do you use cd to "go into" directory in your project or use "dotnet run my/test/project"? You can change the

```
.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
```

to

```
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
```

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() get the directory you are currently located so you have to be in the directory with .csproj to use it, or you second option. It search settings file in output.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but now the application doesn't see my appsettings file The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. I'm running program with cd command inside my application's folder.